# I need to change the entire row colour in Excel when a cell value =1

Tags: excel-formula

I need to change the entire row colour in Excel when a cell value has a "1"
Can this be done?

For example the column G will contain either a 1 or a 0. If the cell has the value  1 then I want the entire row to change colour

Appreciate any help

Comment: Yes with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Yep I have got that far. Was hoping for an example formulae

Comment: `=$G1 = 1` is the formula, the Applies to would be the whole sheet.

Comment: Hi Scott. I am a complete novice really. I had =IF($G1=1) . But how do you make it select that row? Sorry for sounding like a dumb ar*e!!

Comment: If your `applies to:` is the whole sheet then it will do it automatically.

Comment: In the Applies to: box put `1:1048576`

Comment: The 1 in $G1 is relative and will change as needed to the correct row.

Comment: Done that and it still only applies to the single cell with the 1 in it

Comment: Works for me, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is:

```
=$G1 = 1
```

And the Applies to is:

```
=$1:$1048576
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys! It was the applying to range that threw me! Thanks for taking the time to help. Matt

Comment: @Matt please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.